# Grepping, formatting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'd like create a report of UIDs and usernames, in a format similar to:

```
9142   jdoe
9158   jsmith
75488  msteel
```

etc etc

from the "id" command in Unix, which on our system yields results like this:

```
% id jdoe
uid=9142(jdoe) gid=101(users) groups=101(users)
```

Also, in cases where the username doesn't exist:

```
% id asdasdasd
id: asdasdasd: No such user
```

I'd like result to be similar to (with dashes instead of UID that doesn't exist):

```
----   asdasdasd
9142   jdoe
9158   jsmith
75488  msteel
```

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Would you like fries with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ain't pretty, but:

```
sed -e 's/^uid=//;s/).*//;s/(/ /;s/^id:/----/;s/:.*//' | column -t
```

Example output:

```
(id; id root; id daemon; id foobar ) 2>&1 \
| sed -e 's/^uid=//;s/).*//;s/(/ /;s/^id:/----/;s/:.*//' \
| column -t

501   atomlinson
0     root
1     daemon
----  foobar
```

Comment: Hi Alex, that works great except for the id that doesn't exist. I can work around this, however, with if/then within. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: The syntax for "no such user" might be different on your system.  On mine it is "id: foobar: no such user".

Answer (score 1):

```
id $1 > temp
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    cat temp | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'|awk -F'=' '{print $2}'|sed 's/(/ /g'|sed 's/)//g' >> output.txt
else
    echo "------" $1 >> output.txt
fi
rm temp
```